# Spark reducer and summation result issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is sample file

```
Department,Designation,costToCompany,State

    Sales,Trainee,12000,UP
    Sales,Lead,32000,AP
    Sales,Lead,32000,LA
    Sales,Lead,32000,TN
    Sales,Lead,32000,AP
    Sales,Lead,32000,TN 
    Sales,Lead,32000,LA
    Sales,Lead,32000,LA
    Marketing,Associate,18000,TN
    Marketing,Associate,18000,TN
    HR,Manager,58000,TN
```

Produce an output as csv

- Group by department, desigination, State
- With additional columns with sum(costToCompany) and sum(TotalEmployeeCount)

Result should be like

```
Dept,Desg,state,empCount,totalCost
Sales,Lead,AP,2,64000
Sales,Lead,LA,3,96000
Sales,Lead,TN,2,64000
```

**Following is the solution and writing to file is resulting in an error. What am i doing wrong here?**

Step #1: Load file

```
val file = sc.textFile("data/sales.txt")
```

Step #2: Create a case class to represt the data

```
scala> case class emp(Dept:String, Desg:String, totalCost:Double, State:String)
defined class emp
```

Step #3: Split data and create RDD of emp object

```
scala> val fileSplit = file.map(_.split(","))
scala> val data = fileSplit.map(x => emp(x(0), x(1), x(2).toDouble, x(3)))
```

Step #4: Turn the data into Key/value par with key=(dept, desg,state) and value=(1,totalCost)

```
scala> val keyVals = data.map(x => ((x.Dept,x.Desg,x.State),(1,x.totalCost)))
```

Step #5: Group by using reduceByKey,  as we want summation as well for total number of employees and the cost

```
scala> val results = keyVals.reduceByKey{(a,b) => (a._1+b._1, a._2+b._2)} //(a.count+ b.count, a.cost+b.cost)
results: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String, String), (Int, Double))] = ShuffledRDD[41] at reduceByKey at <console>:55
```

Step #6: save the results

```
scala> results.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("data/result")
```

**Error**

```
17/08/16 22:16:59 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 23)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "costToCompany"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
    at $line85.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:51)
    at $line85.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:51)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/08/16 22:16:59 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 23, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "costToCompany"
```

**Update 1**
Forgot to remove header. update code here. Save is throwing a different error now. also, need to put the header back in the file.

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("data/sales.txt")
scala> val header = fileSplit.first()
scala> val noHeaderData = fileSplit.filter(_(0) != header(0))
scala> case class emp(Dept:String, Desg:String, totalCost:Double, State:String)
scala> val data = noHeaderData.map(x => emp(x(0), x(1), x(2).toDouble, x(3)))
scala> val keyVals = data.map(x => ((x.Dept,x.Desg,x.State),(1,x.totalCost)))
scala> val resultSpecific = results.map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._1._3, x._2._1, x._2._2))
scala> resultSpecific.repartition(1).saveASTextFile("data/specific")
<console>:64: error: value saveASTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, Int, Double)]
          resultSpecific.repartition(1).saveASTextFile("data/specific")
```

Comment: Is this part correct? `emp(x(0), x(1), x(2).toDouble, x(3))`, you use the first 4 values in the list, however, looking at your file it should be `emp(x(0), x(1), x(4).toDouble, x(2))`. Also, did you remove the header from the file?

Comment: assignment part is correct. i didnt remove the header. Put update 1 and now saveAsTextFile has a different error. I dont think i need to perform another map operation before saving...

Comment: result is like `(Sales,Lead,AP,2,64000.0)` in the file. how can i 1) add header back 2) save the entries in the file without ( and ) like `Sales,Lead,AP,2,64000.0`

Comment: Using Spark DataFrames would be better here.

Comment: I am new to BigData concepts, am from C# and MVC background. I have to dive into DataFrames but not at this time. I need to get my basic concepts in order first. Also CCA175 exam is all about terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are trying to cast into double, costToCompany string wont cast thats why its stuck when try to fire action. just drop first record from file and then it will work . you can also do such operation on dataframe also which will be easy

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question as well as comments:

It would be easier for you to utilize dataframes in this case, as your file is in csv format you can use the following way to load and save the data. In this way, you do not need to concern yourself with splitting the rows in the file as well as taking care of the header (both when loading and saving).

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
        .load("csv/file/path");
```

The dataframe column names will then be the same as the header in the file. Instead of `reduceByKey()` you can use the dataframe's `groupBy()` and `agg()`:

```
val res = df.groupBy($"Department", $"Designation", $"State")
  .agg(count($"costToCompany").alias("empCount"), sum($"costToCompany").alias("totalCost"))
```

Then save it:

```
res.coalesce(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("results.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is straight forward and it says that

> :64: error: value saveASTextFile is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, Int, Double)]
>             resultSpecific.repartition(1).saveASTextFile("data/specific")

In fact, you got no method called `saveASTextFile(...)`  but `saveAsTextFile(???)`.  you have case error on your method name.